# Why do we treat a passed by reference values as an address?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, pass-by-reference

I found this code:

```
foo::foo(const foo & arg) :
     impl_(new impl(*arg.impl_))
{};
```

As far as I understand this constructor of class `foo` takes another object of the class `foo` as the only argument. What is not clear to me is why do we use `*` in front of `arg`. As far as I know, when we pass arguments by reference, we should treat this arguments in the "body" of the function as normal variables (and not as addresses of the variables, *i.e.* we should not use `*`).

Answer (score 5):

The `.` operator has higher precedence than the indirection (`*`) operator, so your code is parsed as

```
*(arg.impl_)
```

`impl_` appears to be a pointer, because you initialize it with new. To invoke the copy constructor, you have to pass an object, not a pointer, so you need to dereference it beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

This is the copy constructor, and it takes a *const reference* (not an "object") as its argument.

You haven't shown the class definition, but

```
*arg.impl_
```

doesn't mean *dereference `arg` and then look for some member called `impl_`*, that would look like one of:

```
(*arg).impl_
arg->impl_
```

instead it means *dereference the pointer `arg.impl_`*, ie:

```
*(arg.impl_)
```

this is invoking the equivalent copy constructor for whatever type `impl_` is.

---

Sample:

```
struct Impl {
    int i_;

    Impl() : i_(0) {}
    Impl(const Impl& other) : i_(other.i_) {}
};

struct Foo {
    Impl *impl_;

    // Foo::Foo calls Impl::Impl
    Foo() : impl_(new Impl()) {}

    // Foo::Foo(const Foo&) calls Impl::Impl(const Impl&)
    Foo(const Foo& other) : impl_(new Impl(*other.impl_)) {}
};
```

NB. this looks like the *pimpl* (or Pointer to Implementation) idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Because `impl_` is a pointer to a `impl`, which takes a a reference as copy constructor parameter (as is usually the case).